# Oracle SQL sanity check - Join to get most recent created record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Facility/Node table, and a checklist table with a simple query/join to show the currently open checklist (has a null CLOSE_DATE field).

Nodes may or may not have checklists, only one open checklist, multiple closed checklists. Fairly standard stuff.

But now I need to also show the most recently created but closed checklist also and was wanting to get my solution sanity checked before I started integrating it into the real codebase.

NOTE: Oracle SQL

```
CREATE TABLE test_user (user_id number, user_name varchar2(16));
CREATE TABLE test_node (node_id number, node_name varchar2(16));
CREATE TABLE test_list (list_id number, node_id number, user_id number, create_date date, close_date date);
INSERT INTO test_user VALUES (1, 'apple');
INSERT INTO test_user VALUES (2, 'pear');
INSERT INTO test_node VALUES (1, 'facility 1');
INSERT INTO test_node VALUES (2, 'facility 2');
INSERT INTO test_node VALUES (3, 'facility 3');
INSERT INTO test_node VALUES (4, 'facility 4');
INSERT INTO test_list VALUES (1, 1, 1,  '1-jan-2015', NULL);
INSERT INTO test_list VALUES (2, 2, 1, '1-jan-2015', '1-feb-2015');
INSERT INTO test_list VALUES (3, 2, 1, '1-apr-2015', '1-jun-2015');
INSERT INTO test_list VALUES (4, 2, 2, '1-mar-2015', '2-mar-2015');
INSERT INTO test_list VALUES (5, 2, 1, '1-nov-2015', NULL);
INSERT INTO test_list VALUES (6, 4, 2, '1-nov-2015', '15-nov-2015');
```

The user table is mostly part of this to make the left-joins a bit more complex to simulate the actual database.

I am attempting to create a single SQL that will return each Node/Facility, information about its currently open checklist (if any), and information about the most recently closed checklist (if any).

My initial attempt to solve my problem:

```
WITH list_breakout_open AS (
    SELECT  ll.list_id, ll.node_id, ll.create_date,
            ll.user_id, uu.user_name

      FROM  test_list ll
      JOIN  test_user uu ON ll.user_id = uu.user_id
     WHERE  ll.close_date IS NULL
), list_breakout_close AS (
    SELECT  ll.list_id, ll.node_id, ll.create_date, ll.close_date,
            ll.user_id, uu.user_name,
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ll.node_id ORDER BY ll.create_date DESC) AS close_rank

      FROM  test_list ll
      JOIN  test_user uu ON ll.user_id = uu.user_id
     WHERE  ll.close_date IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT  nn.node_id, nn.node_name, 
        lbo.list_id AS open_list_id, lbo.user_name AS open_user_name, lbo.create_date AS open_create_date,
        lbc.list_id AS close_list_id, lbc.user_name AS close_user_name, lbc.create_date AS close_create_date, lbc.close_date AS close_close_date

  FROM  test_node nn
  LEFT JOIN list_breakout_open lbo ON nn.node_id = lbo.node_id
  LEFT JOIN list_breakout_close lbc ON nn.node_id = lbc.node_id
                                    AND close_rank = 1;
```

The tables will never get huge (thousands of rows, not millions), so performance is not a big problem. I am mostly concerned with code maintenance and want a clean query that will make sense when someone looks at this mess 5 years from now.

Does my solution seem sane? Am I missing something obvious that might trip me up later??

edit: added a note about what my final query should do.

Comment: From the data sample you show, what would be the desired result? That would be a plus to your question.

Comment: added a paragraph about what the sql should do. Thanks, Jorge.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it scanning each table once and aggregating with analytic functions as follows:

```
SQL> SELECT n.node_id,
  2         n.node_name,
  3         min(case when l.close_date is null then l.list_id end) keep (dense_rank first order by nvl2(l.close_date, null, l.create_date) desc nulls last) open_list_id,
  4         min(case when l.close_date is null then u.user_name end) keep (dense_rank first order by nvl2(l.close_date, null, l.create_date) desc nulls last) open_user_name,
  5         min(case when l.close_date is null then l.create_date end) keep (dense_rank first order by nvl2(l.close_date, null, l.create_date) desc nulls last) open_create_date,
  6         min(case when l.close_date is not null then l.list_id end) keep (dense_rank first order by nvl2(l.close_date, l.create_date, null) desc nulls last) close_list_id,
  7         min(case when l.close_date is not null then u.user_name end) keep (dense_rank first order by nvl2(l.close_date, l.create_date, null) desc nulls last) close_user_name,
  8         min(case when l.close_date is not null then l.create_date end) keep (dense_rank first order by nvl2(l.close_date, l.create_date, null) desc nulls last) close_create_date,
  9         min(case when l.close_date is not null then l.close_date end) keep (dense_rank first order by nvl2(l.close_date, l.create_date, null) desc nulls last) close_close_date
 10    FROM test_node n
 11    LEFT JOIN test_list l ON l.node_id = n.node_id
 12    LEFT JOIN test_user u ON u.user_id = l.user_id
 13   GROUP BY n.node_id, n.node_name
 14   ORDER BY node_id;
   NODE_ID NODE_NAME        OPEN_LIST_ID OPEN_USER_NAME   OPEN_CREATE_DATE CLOSE_LIST_ID CLOSE_USER_NAME  CLOSE_CREATE_DATE CLOSE_CLOSE_DATE
---------- ---------------- ------------ ---------------- ---------------- ------------- ---------------- ----------------- ----------------
         1 facility 1                  1 apple            01/01/2015                                                        
         2 facility 2                  5 apple            01/11/2015                   3 apple            01/04/2015        01/06/2015
         3 facility 3                                                                                                       
         4 facility 4                                                                  6 pear             01/11/2015        15/11/2015
```

Not totally sure it's the correct output as the others mentioned. I validated it with your posted solution.

Comment: Single scanning the tables would be good. I will test this idea out on my real data set tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a **derived table** approach avoiding window functions, `WITH()` and `RANK()`:

```
SELECT openchecklist.node_id, openchecklist.node_name,
       openchecklist.list_id AS open_list_id, openchecklist.user_name AS open_user_name, 
       openchecklist.create_date AS open_create_date,
       closedchecklist.list_id AS close_list_id, closedchecklist.user_name AS close_user_name, 
       closedchecklist.create_date AS close_create_date, closedchecklist.close_date AS close_close_date

FROM
       (SELECT ll.list_id, ll.node_id, nn.node_name, ll.create_date, 
               ll.user_id, uu.user_name
          FROM (test_list ll
    INNER JOIN test_user uu ON ll.user_id = uu.user_id)
    INNER JOIN test_node nn ON ll.node_id = nn.node_id
         WHERE ll.close_date IS NULL) AS openchecklist

LEFT JOIN

      (SELECT ll.list_id, ll.node_id, nn.node_name, ll.create_date, ll.close_date,
              ll.user_id, uu.user_name        
         FROM (test_list ll
   INNER JOIN test_user uu ON ll.user_id = uu.user_id)
   INNER JOIN test_node nn ON ll.node_id = nn.node_id
        WHERE ll.close_date IS NOT NULL
          AND ll.close_date = (SELECT MAX(close_date)  FROM test_list temp 
                               WHERE temp.node_id = ll.node_id)
       ) As closedchecklist

ON openchecklist.node_id = closedchecklist.node_id
```

Alternatively, consider even a **union query** *(stacked data)* which avoids the expensive column building as data is presented in long format.

```
    SELECT nn.node_id, nn.node_name, ll.list_id,
           uu.user_name, ll.create_date, ll.close_date,
           'OPEN' as status    
      FROM test_list ll
INNER JOIN test_node nn ON ll.node_id = nn.node_id
 LEFT JOIN test_user uu ON ll.user_id = uu.user_id
     WHERE ll.close_date IS NULL
  ORDER BY ll.node_id, ll.create_date DESC

     UNION

    SELECT nn.node_id, nn.node_name, ll.list_id,
           uu.user_name, ll.create_date, ll.close_date,
           'CLOSED' as status               
      FROM test_list ll
INNER JOIN test_node nn ON ll.node_id = nn.node_id
 LEFT JOIN test_user uu ON ll.user_id = uu.user_id
     WHERE ll.close_date IS NOT NULL
       AND ll.close_date = (SELECT MAX(close_date)  FROM test_list temp 
                            WHERE temp.node_id = ll.node_id)
```